# Zombie Toys movement script not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I linked pictures of my error codes I've tried everything. Please someone look at it and let me know what I did wrong. I'm trying to do the Zombie Toys game [Error][Error][Error][Error][Error][Error]

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;

    Vector3 movement;
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    int floorMask;
    float camRayLength = 100f;

    void Awake ()
    {
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Move(h, v);
        Turning();
        Animating(h, v);
    }

    void Move (float h, float v)
    {
        movement.Set(h, 0f, v);

        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }

    void Turning ()
    {
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit floorHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, CamRayLength, floorMask)) ;
        {
            Vector3 playertoMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playertoMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
        }
    }
    void Animating (float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are case-sensitive in C#.

You declared the `Vector3` variable as `playertoMouse` but then the next line you are trying to use `playerToMouse` with `playerToMouse.y = 0f;`. Notice that the `T` in `To` is capitalized instead of lower-case `t` as declared.

I suggest you capitalize that `t` everywhere so that `to` becomes `To` as that's more easier to read than making it a lower-case `t`.

```
void Turning ()
{
    Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit floorHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, CamRayLength, floorMask)) ;
    {
        Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
        playerToMouse.y = 0f;

        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
        playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anytime... Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if your problem is solved.